# How to create hamburger menu icon consisting from single SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg

The SVG code of Material design Hamburger menu icon:

[image]

```xml
<svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M3,6H21V8H3V6M3,11H21V13H3V11M3,16H21V18H3V16Z" />
</svg>
```

However it always could be some reason I can not use the Material Design icon and need to create my own one. But how I can reach such simple code? One `path`.

Tried to draw the similar icon in AbodeXD. The output SVG code was:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="26" height="18" viewBox="0 0 26 18">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-アートボード_1">
      <rect width="26" height="18"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="アートボード_1" data-name="アートボード – 1" clip-path="url(#clip-アートボード_1)">
    <line id="線_1" data-name="線 1" x2="26" transform="translate(0 0.5)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1"/>
    <line id="線_2" data-name="線 2" x2="26" transform="translate(0 17.5)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1"/>
    <line id="線_3" data-name="線 3" x2="26" transform="translate(0 9)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The [SVG optimization](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) reduced above code to:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="18">
   <defs>
      <clipPath id="a">
         <path d="M0 0h26v18H0z"/>
      </clipPath>
   </defs>
   <g data-name="アートボード – 1" clip-path="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke="#000">
      <path data-name="線 1" d="M0 .5h26"/>
      <path data-name="線 2" d="M0 17.5h26"/>
      <path data-name="線 3" d="M0 9h26"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

But it a more complicated than Material Design SVG. Also, we can't change the icon color by like `fill: red` as many other icons.

Comment: I'm confused. You literally have the path code from the material design icon. Why can't you use that path? (Adobe tools produce terrible SVG - Figma generates better SVG)

Comment: @MichaelMullany, thank you for the comment. I can't use this path because Material design icon has paddings, by other word, this path does not fill the canvas.

Comment: @MichaelMullany The material design icons has 24x24 viewbox, while the imaginary rectangle in which path inscribed usually has side19~22. I will be great to customize the path from Material Design, but it's path is too complicated to understand how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path syntax is easy to understand - let's break it down:

```
<path fill="currentColor" d="M3,6H21V8H3V6M3,11H21V13H3V11M3,16H21V18H3V16Z" />
```

M3,6 - **M**ove the drawing point to coordinates [3,6]

H21 - draw a **H**orizontal line to coordinates [21,Current Y Coordinate (6)]

V8 - draw a **V**ertical line to coordinates [Current X Coordinate (21), 8]

H3 - draw a **H**orizontal line to coordinates [3,Current Y Coordinate (8)]

V6 - etc.

M3,11 - **M**ove the drawing point to coordinates [3,11]

... etc

Z - Draw a line to the start of the current subpath (the coordinates of the last MoveTo - which in this case, doesn't do anything, because we're already at those coordinates)

So if you want the hamburger menu to be in a smaller viewBox, you can edit the path by hand like so:

```html
<svg style="width:20px;height:20px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M1,4 H18 V6 H1 V4 M1,9 H18 V11 H1 V7 M3,14 H18 V16 H1 V14" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You make me to don't afraid the SVG. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Please Use **stroke="red"** rather than using Fill="red"

Please find the Below updated code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="18">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
            <path d="M0 0h26v18H0z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g data-name="アートボード – 1" clip-path="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke="red">
        <path data-name="線 1" d="M0 .5h26"/>
        <path data-name="線 2" d="M0 17.5h26"/>
        <path data-name="線 3" d="M0 9h26"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```